# Como adicionar chave estrangeira com constraint e alter table no Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

Eu tenho as seguintes tabelas :

```
Create table OS(
nro_os      number(4),
data_os        date ,
hora_os        number(4)
);

Create table cliente(
cod_cliente       number(4),
nome_cliente      varchar(12),
endereco_cliente  varchar(20),
telefone_cliente  number(11)
);
```

E eu tenho a seguinte ALTER TABLE :

```
Alter table OS
add (constraint cliente_cod_cliente_fk foreign key (cod_cliente) references cliente (cod_cliente));
```

Só que quando eu vou rodar a query, ele me retorna o erro :

> ORA-00904: "COD-CLIENTE": identificador inválido

Como posso adicionar a chave estrangeira com o ALTER TABLE de forma correta ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você não possui a coluna **cod_cliente** na tabela OS, adicione-a e irá funcionar.

Seu esquema ficaria assim:

```
Create table OS(
nro_os      number(4),
data_os        date ,
hora_os        number(4),
cod_cliente number(4)
);

Create table cliente(
cod_cliente       number(4) primary key,
nome_cliente      varchar(12),
endereco_cliente  varchar(20),
telefone_cliente  number(11)
);

ALTER TABLE OS
ADD CONSTRAINT cliente_cod_cliente_fk 
  FOREIGN KEY (cod_cliente)
  REFERENCES cliente(cod_cliente);
```

Para inserir a coluna e a chave estrangeira ao mesmo tempo:

```
ALTER TABLE OS
ADD cod_cliente number(4) CONSTRAINT cliente_cod_cliente_fk 
  REFERENCES cliente(cod_cliente);
```

Comment: Olá, eu posso adicionar a foreign key sem antes ter que adicionar o atributo na tabela ? Sem ter que colocar o cod_cliente na OS, e ir simplesmente adicionando com o alter table ?

Comment: Você pode fazer tudo em um `ALTER TABLE`, onde cria o atributo e a constraint ao mesmo tempo, vou incluir na resposta.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta mais completa, +1 e resposta correta.

Answer (score 3):

O comando é bem simples, acredito que seu problema pode ser no parentese, teste assim:

```
ALTER TABLE OS
ADD CONSTRAINT cliente_cod_cliente_fk 
  FOREIGN KEY (cod_cliente)
  REFERENCES supplier(cod_cliente);
```

Mais duvidas: https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/foreign_keys/foreign_keys.php